# ftell always returns -1

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a function that will kill instances by program name in string

```
unsigned int kill_all_program_instances(const char * program_name){
    int res;
    char buf[1024];
    string first;
    string second;
    int lSize, pid , pos;
    string command="pidof ";
    FILE *fd;
    memset(buf,'\0',sizeof(buf));
    fd=popen((command+program_name).c_str(),"r");
    unsigned int mypid = getpid();
    if(fd != NULL){ 
    fseek (fd , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(fd);
    rewind (fd);
    if (lSize <= 0)
    {
        printf("lsize is %d\n",lSize);
        pclose(fd);
        return 0;
    }
            .....
}
```

This is just the beginning of the function, but I always get -1 for lSize.
I ran

```
pidof chromium-browse
```

and got

```
26487 19353 16993 11504 10960 10880 10868 10829 10825 10805 8607 8263 8154 8089 7764 3965 3950
```

however when I run

```
kill_all_program_instances('chromium-browse')
```

I still get -1 for lSize.

Any idea whats wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at `errno` and `strerror()`?

Comment: Can you check is there is an error with `errno` etc.?

Comment: And see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/ftell) too

Comment: Also check the return value of fseek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the comment/answer about detecting errors for `popen` (which doesn't seem correct), I do believe the actual problem is that you are trying to use fseek/ftell on a pipe, which is not a valid operation. A pipe is not a "file" in the conventional sense, it's a stream of data where each data item can only be read once.

Just read using `fscanf()` or something similar, until it gives you an EOF.

Answer (score 0):

popen() communicates with the spawned process using pipes. pipes are not seekable.

You simply cannot use fseek/ftell on the FILE* returned by popen, they will always fail.